# React Testing library with testIdAttribute

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a Form with children components for input fields, i want to make a test for this input component with the id. The ID is created with useId if it isn't provided so it is dynamically.
How can this be done?

```
test("Input Test", () => {
  const Wrapper = (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const formMethods = useForm();
    return <FormProvider {...formMethods}>{props.children}</FormProvider>;
  };

  render(
    <Wrapper>
      <InputField name={"First Name"} label={"fname"} type={"text"} />
      <InputField name={"Last Name"} label={"lname"} type={"text"} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
  configure({ testIdAttribute: "id" });

  const inputfname = screen.getByTestId("fname");
  const inputlname = screen.getByTestId("lname");

  expect(inputfname).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(inputlname).toBeInTheDocument();

});
```

```
  const fieldId = id ?? useId();

  <label htmlFor={fieldId}>{label}</label>
  <input
     id={fieldId}
     {...props}
   />
```

Comment: Why don't you use the [top priority query](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#priority) of finding the component by _role_, in which case the specific value of the ID (which is **not** the same as a test ID) is irrelevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test with test-id you have to write your html element like this:

```html
<div data-testid="custom-id" />
```

You can check the docs [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid/).

And because `useId()` is a random thing so you can't test it because you don't know the value, so it's better to test your component with another thing.